# Walks in Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose $H$ and $G$ are connected of order $n$. Let $c_k(G)$ and $c_k(H)$ denote the number of closed walks of length $k$ in $G$ and $H$, respectively. Let $m(G)$ and $m(H)$ are the number of edges in $G$ and $H$, respectively. I was trying to prove the following:

If $m(H)<m(G)$, then $$c_k(H)\leq c_k(G)$$ for all $k\geq 2$. Perhaps it's not true.

Comment: I don't think it's true. Suppose that your graphs are simple. Let $A,B$ be the adjacency matrix of $H$ and $G$, respectively. You want to prove that if $\mathrm{Tr}(A^2) < \mathrm{Tr}(B^2) $ then $\mathrm{Tr}(A^k) \le \mathrm{Tr}(B^k)$ for all $k\ge 2$.

Answer (score 2):

It's obviously true if the edge set $H$ is the subset of the edge set of $G$, since any walk in $H$ is a walk in $G$ (assuming the same vertex set).

The simplest counterexamples involve bipartite graphs: they don't have closed walks of odd length.  So a 5-cycle has a closed walk of length 5, but any bipartite graph on 5 vertices does not.

[image]

From left. A bipartite graph on $5$ vertices with $6$ edges $-$ this has no closed walks of length $5$.

From right. A $5$-cycle (with $5$ edges) $-$ this has closed walks of length $5$.

Comment: Rebecca, sorry, but I have two black rectangles on my screen instead of your pictures.

Comment: @kabenyuk Thanks!  That's exactly right.